# Android Voicemail Settings

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-spica, voicemail

Voicemail on my T-Mobile Galaxy Portal/Spica/i5700 doesn't work.  I've set it up via the Tmobile voicemail setup, but if I call my mobile it just rings and rings until I get a message saying 'This number is currently unavailable.'

Is there anything in Android itself that might have borked it?  I'm running an *ahem* not official Samsung version of Froyo.  In `Settings -> Call Settings` I can see `Voicemail service`, from which my only option is `My Carrier`, and `Voicemail Settings`, and all that lets me do is pick the voicemail number to call.

Or is it more likely just some error at T-mobile's end?  Thought I'd check before giving them a call.

Comment: @ngm Was it working before you loaded a custom ROM on your device? Personally I use [Google Voice](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googlevoice&feature=search_result) for my voicemail - works great

Comment: @Daniel I'm sure it does, if you're in the US. Google Voice isn't available to us Europeans on the other side of the pond.

Comment: @Daniel As far as I recall, it has never worked.  I've certainly never received a voicemail on it, and I had it for about 6 months before I put the custom ROM on.

Comment: @GAThrawn Dude thats lame.  I had no idea.

Comment: @ngm I would check with T-mobile then.  Unless another person here can say that voicemail on T-mobile doesn't work well with Android my guess is that there is something wrong on their part

Comment: I agree with @Daniel, call tmobile and make sure voice mail is set up on the line. When I added my sons line, it didnt have voice mail set up, i had to call and they said it want "activated" on their end.

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually setup your voicemail with TMobile as well as on your phone.

You simply ring 222 from the phone.

Here is a detailed description:

http://forums.t-mobile.co.uk/help-and-support/index?page=home&cat=VOICEMAIL